# Tools to test SOAP Request

Tags: open-source

I am using SOAP UI for SOAP request. Can someone suggest few open sources to test SOAP request other than SOAP UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a paper last term on SOAP communications, I always check at programmableweb.com for APIs.

I ended up using the country information at

http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso

And

a basic calculator service

http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx

Comment: I'm looking for a tool like SOAP UI and not for API.

Answer (score 0):

- [SoapUI Alternatives](https://www.educba.com/soapui-alternatives/) - some are free
- [Top 3 SoapUI Alternatives in 2020 | Research Done For You](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/soapui-alternatives-api-testing/)  plugs its own, which is free, but also metions two others.
- Quora (hiss! ;-) question, [Is there any SoapUI alternative?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-SoapUI-alternative)
- [alternatives](https://alternative.me/soapui)

although I prefer [this alternative site](https://alternativeto.net/). Here's its results for [free alternatives to SoapUI](https://alternativeto.net/software/soapui/?license=free).

And, finally, [19 Best SoapUI Alternatives in 2021](https://www.guru99.com/soapui-alternative.html) does not say which are free, but it does boast the excellent [PostMan](https://www.postman.com/), which is the best API test tool that I know (and I am constantly searching), which is free and handles SOAP.